# Exclude code from production in Android, Java

Tags: java, android

I am having some code in my Android application that I use for debugging but don't want to have in production. Is there a way in Android, Java to exclude some code in production version? Like in C with define, ifdef, endif?

I was into assertion, which can be enabled in run configuration of the Android application, but that assert statement requires the assert code to return a boolean value so that doesn't work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the debugging code to be omitted from the compiled bytecode or do you just don't want the debugging code to ever run?

Comment: It's good enough for me if code doesn't run, but the best would be if it was omitted from the compiled byte code.

Comment: @Geobits That solution you link to is nice, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer for informational purposes and this is not a recommendation actually use assertion side effects to alter code.

That being said...

```
    boolean debug = false;
    assert debug = true;

    if(debug){
        /* Do debugging stuff */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no native conditional compilation in Java.  However, this article details a way to do it using ANT and comments such as `//[ifdef]` and `//[enddef]`

https://weblogs.java.net/blog/schaefa/archive/2005/01/how_to_do_condi.html

Good luck!

Comment: Interesting, I was quite sure that there would be some native conditional compilation in Java, but apparently not. I will look through your link but I think for my needs the link @Geobits posted holds a solution that works good enough for me

Answer (score 0):

There is also this solution, which adds preprocessor directives to Java:

https://www.java.net//forum/topic/java-tools/java-development-tools/wwyt-conditional-compilation-pre-processor